# How do I migrate if Laravel has a DB connection with Read/Write settings?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am currently creating a DB with a Read/Write configuration in Laravel 10.

Two DBs are created in Docker.

```
version: "3"
services:
    mysql:
        image: "mysql/mysql-server:8.0"
        ports:
            - "${FORWARD_WRITE_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
            MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - "sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "./vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh"
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s

    mysql_read:
        image: "mysql/mysql-server:8.0"
        ports:
            - "${FORWARD_READ_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
            MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - "mysql-read:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "./vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh"
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    mysql-read:
        driver: local
```

Connection information was created in Laravel based on the DB created.

```
database.php

...
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url'    => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'read'   => [
                'host' => env('READ_DB_HOST', 'mysql_read'),
                'port' => env('READ_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            ],
            'write'  => [
                'host' => env('WRITE_DB_HOST', 'mysql'),
                'port' => env('WRITE_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            ],
            'sticky' => true,
            'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket'    => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset'        => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation'      => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'         => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict'         => true,
            'engine'         => null,
            'options'        => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
...
```

It was confirmed that read DB is used during SELECT process, INSERT and UPDATE process, and write DB is used during UPDATE process.
However, when I run `php artisan migrate`, only the write DB is migrated.

Is there any way to add tables to the read DB as well?

Comment: When using Laravel's lead replica configuration, the `artisan migrate` command is designed to migrate the database schema on the primary database connection, not the lead replica. This behavior is by design; migration usually involves changes to the database structure and must be done on the primary database to ensure consistency across all replicas.

We have found that this is the case.
So, do you manually create DB tables for replicas?